# Why not Back propagate through time in LSTM , similar to RNN

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, calculus, back-propagation-through-time

I'm trying to implement RNN and LSTM , many-to-many architecture. I reasoned myself why BPTT is necessary in RNNs and it makes sense.

But what doesn't make sense to me is, most of resources I went through online for LSTM back prop (like attachment ) and this one :  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rQPJnyGLlY

Seems to be doing more of back propagation w.r.t current time stamp itself, but not through time , keeping variable convention aside, similar to RNN , I would assume that when calculating DL w.r.t Wf, since both current time step and previous hidden states are made up of Wf, both needs to added together, but most derivations I found are not doing that.

Specifically, taking coursers's notation, forward prop:

```
ft = sigmoid( Wf.(at-1, xt) + bf )
it = sigmoid(Wi.(at-1, xt) + bi )
ctil = Tanh(Wc.(at-1, xt) + bc )

ct = ft * ct-1 + it*ctil
ot = sigmoid(Wo.(at-1, xt) + bo )
at = ot * Tanh(ct)
yhat_t = Softmax(Wy.at + by )
```

Since at-1 and ot both have Wo in their equations, I would assume following derivation for dWo:

```
dWo = dat * (1-T(ct)**2 ) * ot* (1-ot )*(at-1,xt)-dot part + dotat-1 * dat-1ot-1 * dot-1Wo
```

Above derivation contains dot + dot-1. But derivation given by coursera, only contains dot and not dot-1.

And in the derivations of update and forget gates, what follows after plus sign, shouldn't they be t-1 and not t ?

So, I'm assuming LSTM back-prop doesn't involve BPTT , could someone please enlighten me on this ?

I'm specifically looking for the right theoretical derivation of BP in LSTMs, and if they involve BPTT in theory or not.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks !

[image: Coursera LSTM Backprop Derivation]

Answer (score 1):

There is no "right" theoretical backpropagation in LSTMs. They did evolve over time and change. I find this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.04069) very useful for understanding LSTMs.

Following a quote from there (obviously in the paper you will also find the sources refernced there.

> **History of LSTM:** The initial version of the LSTM block [14, 15]
> included (possibly multiple) cells, input and output gates, but no
> forget gate and no peephole connections. The output gate, unit biases,
> or input activation function were omitted for certain experiments.
> Training was done using a mixture of Real-Time Recurrent Learning
> (RTRL) [23, 24] and Backpropagation Through Time (BPTT) [24, 25].
>
> ***Only the gradient of the cell was propagated back through time, and
> the gradient for the other recurrent connections was truncated***. Thus,
> that study did not use the exact gradient for training. Another
> feature of that version was the use of full gate recurrence, which
> means that all the gates received recurrent inputs from all gates at
> the previous time-step in addition to the recurrent inputs from the
> block outputs. This feature did not appear in any of the later papers.

Hope this helps. Otherwise I would also recommend looking for help in another community. Or rephrase your problem into a coding problem.

Comment: Thanks @mrk , so, if the paper didn't deliberately back propagate gradients through time for certain weights; from your perspective , do you think Tensorflow and other modern frameworks would also be limiting BPTT in practice ? If so, modern LSTMs in practice would converge slowly, then their theoretical counterparts right ( assuming there is perfect backprop exists in theory )?

Comment: Not sure about keras use in practice. Probably it worth taking a look at their implementation: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.15.0/keras/layers/rnn/lstm.py#L45-L379